# Do I need the x_card_num in live mode for Authorize.Net?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net

I am using the authorizenet payment gateway. I am sending the parameter to the authorizenet with `x_test_request=TRUE` . Upon redirecting to the authorizenet it is giving me this error:

```
3,2,33,(TESTMODE) Credit card number is required.,000000,P,0,774,,100.00,CC,auth_capture,4,vaibhav,Saxena,,test,delhi,,250002,IN,9310974585,,vaibhav1407@gmail.com,,,,,,,,,,,,,,908EB9BC737024E17
```

Do I need to pass the card number in test mode or if I need to do I still need to pass it in live mode?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass it in live mode and test mode. The credit card number is obviously the most important piece of information when processing a credit card payment so how can you test your integration without it?